# Detect when there are no more touches without counting

Tags: ios, uiview, uitouch

I'm trying to detect the point at which there are no more touches on screen.

I've tried keeping a running total of touches by counting in touchesbegan and touchesended - but, since I unavoidably have to deal with touches within both super and sub views, the behavior of when those methods are called doesn't make it possible (e.g. if a user touches and then slides off a subview and then back on to that same subview, touchesBegan is called when sliding on but touchesEnded is not called when sliding off).

Does anyone have a reliable method for detecting when there are no touches left on screen?

Many thanks!

D

Comment: Why don't you put a transparent view on top which covers all subviews and will tell you reliably when all fingers are off the screen?

Comment: Thanks - but I don't understand how that would work.  If I put the view on top even if it is visually transparent, won't it intercept all touches - which means I can't deal with the touches at the subview level?

Answer (score 0):

Put a transparent view on top and have it check whether there are still touches ongoing. It should cover all subviews, so a touch moving in or out of a subview does not create artificial `touchesBegan` calls. Track touches and don't miss the last `touchEnded` call: This will tell you that all fingers are now off the screen.

If your other views don't receive touches anymore, be sure to call `super touchesBegan/Moved/Ended`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971739/iphone-what-does-super-touchesbegan-moved-ended-do) for a good explanation what this does.

Comment: I don't see any way of structuring the views so that a view on top of my subviews will send touch events to the subviews when super is called.  Calling super would send the events up to the superview and all my subviews can't be the superview of the new top view.